# sencha command not creating compressed js

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am attempting to use sencha v2.0.0 Beta 3 to create compressed versions of my scripts.

I have a file called mdisp.html which has the following references to ExtJS scripts:

```
<script src="scripts/stores.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/menus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/parts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/user.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am using the following commands to create the compressed scripts:

```
sencha create jsb -a http://localhost:8100/display/mdisp.html -p mdisp.jsb3 -v
```

and

```
sencha build -p mdisp.jsb3 -d . -v
```

What seems to be happening is that there is nothing in either of the generated js files!

Am I missing something here? Is there something I need to change in order to get this to work???

Someone please advise...

Comment: Are you adding bootstrap.js or ext.js in script tag too? Where? Before those or after?

Comment: I am not using bootstrap.js, I am using ext.js. I am also aware, however, that I still have a lot to learn about using the sencha command line. I am in the process of learning more about it. I will return when I know more and can ask more intelligent questions about it.